# Search engines that support searching by <META> tags

Tags: search, meta-tags

I'd like to be able to find websites that have specific metatags: eg

```
<meta name="generator" content="http://www.jadu.net" />
<meta name="DC.subject" lang="en" scheme="eGMS.IPSV" content="Local government;Government, politics and public administration" />
```

Are there any search engines that do this? I'd rather not have to spider most of the `.gov.uk` space...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the meta operator in Bing?

Comment: Looks really promising: is there a particular syntax you can use? It looks like it's supposed to be `literalmeta:generator(http://www.jadu.net)` but that doesn't seem to work...